# Run 2 sql statement 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in my database

**table users**

*user_id auto*

**table2 gallery**

*id auto

user_id*

when the user register while it inserts the info to the user table,**which works** I want to send the user_id to the gallery user_id field.

I have tried the following

```
$connection = dbconnect();
$stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users(user_email, username, user_pwd) VALUES (?,?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $email, $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();


$connection = dbconnect();
$last_row = mysqli_insert_id($connection);


$connection = dbconnect();
$stmt2 = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO gallery(user_id) VALUES (?)');
$stmt2->bind_param('s', $last_row);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->close();
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: it runs the first query fine but it wont insert the last id in the user id of the next table

Comment: select max(user_id) from user table and then insert it into gallery table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to create a new connection to get last insert id. Instead you can do it like:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users(user_email, username, user_pwd) VALUES (?,?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $email, $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$last_row = $stmt->insert_id;
$stmt->close();

$connection = dbconnect();
$stmt2 = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO gallery(user_id) VALUES (?)');
$stmt2->bind_param('s', $last_row);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->close();
```

Also, if your user_id is an integer, you could bind the `$last_row` as "i".

Other than these, you should show the error you're getting in your question.

Comment: Ithere is no error it just dont insert the last id into the gallery table

Comment: Have you tried `$stmt->insert_id;` instead? @Case :)

Comment: Note that *I think*, it would work only before close()

Comment: Great :) yeah I can totally relate to that, have a good one @Case